# Not able to add arguments based on constructor in my Flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

I've created a list of images and I want to display them in cards layout in GridView. Also I created a constructor with properties Color backgroundColor and AssetImage assetImage. This constructor is in a different class Home() so that in my material app I can call it in "home" property. But Home() is asking for 2 arguments and I'm not able to fix this. What should I do? And yeah I'm building an all-in-one websites app so webView is also in the code.

```
void main() => runApp(
  MaterialApp(
    routes: {
      "/webview": (_) => WebviewScaffold(
            withJavascript: true,
            withLocalStorage: true,
            url: 'https://www.google.com/',
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Browser'),
            ),
          ),
    },
    home: Home(),
  ),
);
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
 const Home(this.backgroundColor, this.assetImage);
 final Color backgroundColor;
 final AssetImage assetImage;
 @override
_HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
 final webView = FlutterWebviewPlugin();
 @override
void initState() {
super.initState();
webView.close();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  var gridView = new GridView.builder(
      itemCount: 24,
      gridDelegate:
          new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 3),
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return new GestureDetector(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(6),
            child: Card(
              color: widget.backgroundColor,
              child: new InkWell(
                onTap: () {},
                child: Center(
                child: Image(
                  image: widget.assetImage,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          onTap: () {},
        );
      });

  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('ANytHiNg'),
      backgroundColor: Colors.green,
    ),
    body: gridView,
  );
}
```

}

Comment: If you don't you pass 2 arguments in Home() then you must remove constructor. You can pass the assets image and color directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can may find [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/long-lists#complete-example) helpful.

where you can pass list like this to the constructor,

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp(
    items: List<String>.generate(10000, (i) => "Item $i"),
  ));
}
```

after this get the list by this,

```
MyApp({Key key, @required this.items}) : super(key: key);
```

Comment: I actually have a list of images so any other way if you can help? Thank you.

Comment: @YashJha see my updated answer, you will get an idea about this.

Comment: Ok so everything is looking good now but just one thing is left and that is the "home" property of the MaterialApp(). I'm still not able to do this correctly. My code is divided in three parts: main.dart(where routes are also defined), home.dart(Home class) and list.dart(the list of images). And for the routes, "home" property must be defined. I've done it like this:

Comment: home: Home(assetImage: *here*),); //MaterialApp Ends here! So what should be there at the place of *here* in the code?

Comment: @YashJha you should pass assestImage parameter, in your case that is a list. see in the link in my answer I have passed ```List<String>.generate(10000, (i) => "Item $i")```.